# Count number of characters/words/lines in LibreOffice/OpenOffice(using terminal) Using `wc` command

Tags: command-line, libreoffice, openoffice.org

The command `wc` which is used for counting doesn't work directly with Office files.

For example I created a writer `.odt` file and I wrote inside 7 words. Then i tried `wc -w file.odt` the output was 136 which is not logical at all.

If you try the above on any file you can just `wc -w` without problems.

Now my question is how to use `wc` command with Libre/OpenOffice?

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: You can use `libreoffice`, which is installed by default, to convert the file to a plain text file and then count the characters / words / lines using `wc`:

To count the characters:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to txt:Text <path_to_source_file> &> /dev/null && < <plaint_text_file_name> wc -c && rm test.txt
```

<sub>*<path_to_odt_file> = path to the source file; <plain_text_file_name> = name of source file with the extension replaced to `.txt`;</sub>

To count the words:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to txt:Text <path_to_source_file> &> /dev/null && < <plaint_text_file_name> wc -w && rm test.txt
```

<sub>*<path_to_odt_file> = path to the source file; <plain_text_file_name> = name of source file with the extension replaced to `.txt`;</sub>

To count the lines:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to txt:Text <path_to_source_file> &> /dev/null && < <plaint_text_file_name> wc -l && rm test.txt
```

<sub>*<path_to_odt_file> = path to the source file; <plain_text_file_name> = name of source file with the extension replaced to `.txt`;</sub>

Comment: What is the purpose of rm test.txt?

Answer (score 1):

I found this command:

To count number of words

```
unzip -p doc.odt content.xml | sed 's|<[^>]*>| |g' | wc -w
```

To count number of Lines

```
unzip -p doc.odt content.xml | sed 's|<[^>]*>| |g' | wc -l
```

To count number of characters

```
unzip -p doc.odt content.xml | sed 's|<[^>]*>| |g' | wc -c
```

Comment: Are you sure that regex doesn't match unwanted things also? How does it cater for cases where there's a `<footag>`-like string as plain text within the document body? If a tag it's escaped with a backslash in the XML file I think that that regex would match it regardless (consider `\<\>` within a line for characters count). I'd like to upvote this answer because it doesn't require additional software to be installed, but I fear that it could mess up the output before the counts take place, messing the counts as well

Comment: Give it a try and see what happen

Comment: Looks like it does, `echo '\<\>' | sed 's|<[^>]*>| |g' | wc -c` outputs `3` (the backslash, the backspace to which the match has been replaced to and the newline), plus there's something else wrong with it because `unzip -p test.odt content.xml | sed 's|<[^>]*>| |g' | wc -c`, with `test.odt` containing only `<>`, outputs `37`

Answer (score 1):

There's also the standalone [`odt2txt`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/odt2txt/) (the `unoconv` package also offers `odt2txt`):

```
sudo apt-get install odt2txt
odt2txt foo.odt | wc -w
```

The Ubuntu manpages surprisingly lack a manpage for it.